# In slack, how can I find the target channel of a webhook

Tags: webhooks, slack

I'm working with legacy software and I've come across a slack webhook url.

How can I find its target / destination?

Comment: Depending on your use case, the easiest thing might be to just test the webhook and see where the message ends up.

Comment: I did try! It worked for one that I was looking for, but not the other. Also, I got the reply "ok", meaning that the webhook still works. Otherwise it replies with "invalid_token".

Comment: You can get the WorkspaceId/TeamId from the Webhook URL,  https://hooks.slack.com/services/Txxxxxxxxx (Team Id)/......

You can search your message in this workspace.